# Python - Print error message if cell is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have to call a python script from Excel and I need to check that the data is clean.

I will get the dataframes from excel files. One unacceptable scenario is to have an empty value in one specific column in the df.

I would like to print an error message and exit the script when in that column a value is empty.

Something like:

```
if df['columnX'] is empty
    print "error message"
    sys.exit()
```

Not sure what is an efficient way to deal with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for check if all values are `NaN` - output is boolean mask - `True` and `False` values.

Then need [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) if need check if all values are `True` or [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) if need check if at least one is `True`.

Output is scalar `True` or `False`:

```
if df['columnX'].isnull().all():
    print "error message"
    sys.exit()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnX':[np.nan] * 3})
print (df)
   columnX
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN

print (df['columnX'].isnull())
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: columnX, dtype: bool

print (df['columnX'].isnull().all())
True

print (df['columnX'].isnull().any())
True

if df['columnX'].isnull().all():
    print "error message"
    sys.exit()
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnX':[np.nan] * 3 + [5.6]})
print (df)
   columnX
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      5.6

print (df['columnX'].isnull())
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: columnX, dtype: bool

print (df['columnX'].isnull().all())
False

print (df['columnX'].isnull().any())
True
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be isnull().any() in this case?

Comment: @A-Za-z - Thanks for comment, I add to solution difference between `all` and `any`